# Ef (core) 6 : Is Include needed just for filtering?

Tags: linq, ef-core-6.0

My question is so basic that I can't find topics that answer it; or if they do, they focus on the "hard part" of whatever question was asked, and never on the absolutely obvious aspect -- which I'm about to ask.

Here goes :

If I want to ***filter*** the Blogs on some property of Post (without ***including*** the Post in the result), then **do I need an Include statement?**

In other words :

Will this return all the Blogs that have a Post with an empty title...

```
var badBlogs = context.Blogs
   .Where(b => b.Posts.Any(p => p.Title == String.Empty));
```

...Or do I absolutely need this for the filtering to work as expected :

```
var badBlogs = context.Blogs
   .Include(b => b.Posts) // <-- this
   .Where(b => b.Posts.Any(p => p.Title == String.Empty));
```

Note: I'm using the traditional Blog/Post/Author structure of all EF examples

Comment: No, you do not need `Include` for filtering. And there is no documentation which claims about that. `Include` for LOADING related entities, only for that. Use `Include` only when needed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks. If you write that as an answer I'll check it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Include/ThenInclude` has a purpose only when loading related entities. It has no effect on filter or other LINQ operators.

`Include` works only when retrieved full object from database. It means that if you have `Select`, `Include` can be ignored:

```cs
var badBlogs = context.Blogs
   .Include(b => b.Posts) 
   .Select(b => new Blog { Id = b.Id, ... }); // Include ignored
```

But not in this case:

```cs
var badBlogs = context.Blogs
   .Include(b => b.Posts) 
   .Select(b => new { Blog = b }); // Include works
```

We still retrieve full object but projected to property.

Comment: I would suggest to change "Include only wrks when" to "Include has a purpose only when...".